# How to select distinct-columns along with one nondistinct-column in DB2?

Tags: select, db2, distinct

I need to perform distinct select on few columns out of which, one column is non-distinct. Can I specify which columns make up the distinct group in my SQL statement.

Currently I am doing this.

```
Select distinct a,b,c,d from TABLE_1 inner join TABLE_2 on TABLE_1.a = TABLE_2.a where TABLE_2.d IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem I have is I am getting 2 rows for the above SQL because **column D** holds different values. How can I form a distinct group of columns (a,b&c) ignoring column d, but have column d in my select clause as well?

FYI: I am using DB2

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: ... Do you want every value of `d`, or just (some particular) one?  And could we get your table structures?  There are a couple of different ways to do this...

Comment: X-Zero is right - if you have more than one value of d, which value do you want to appear in the results?

Comment: @X-Zero 
Usually we check if `d` is NOT NULL. I modified my query to reflect that.

Comment: Again, what happens if there is more than one unique value for `d`, when it isn't null?  Do you want all values to appear, or some specific value?  Oh, and add the `d is not null` as part of the join condition (although the optimizer is probably doing that anyways).

Comment: @X-Zero I am Sorry, should have explained it earlier. Usually `d` in my real tables would be `ACTION_CODE` which can take up 3 values Add,Delete and Change.

So ideally I need to pick rows that have `ACTION_CODE` as either `Add` or the one with latest time stamp for `ACTION_CODE=Change`(If there r multiple rows with action code = change)

Comment: @Sandeep - What happens if there is both an `Add` and (one or more) `Change` records?  Do you only want the most recent activity, the `Add` record, or what?  And what about the `Delete` records - should they just be ignored, or should their existence exclude the rest of the related rows from appearing?  Please also append your table structures (real or anonymized), so we can help you better.

Comment: @X-Zero, I was confirming with the business folks. OK we need to pick a record that has latest update time stamp for the column where ACTION_CODE = change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question, even with refinements, is still pretty general.  So, you get a general answer.

Without knowing more about your table structure or your desired results, it may be impossible to give a meaningful answer, but here goes:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM table_1 as t1
JOIN table_2 as t2
ON t2.a = t1.a
AND t2.[some_timestamp_column] = (SELECT MAX(t3.[some_timestamp_column])
                                  FROM table_2 as t3
                                  WHERE t3.a = t2.a)
```

This assumes that `table_1` is populated with single rows to retrieve, and that the one-to-many relationship between `table_1` and `table_2` is created because of different values of `d`, populated at unique `[some_timestamp_column]` times.  If this is the case, it will get the most-recent `table_2` record that matches to `table_1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a,b,c,MAX(d) 
FROM table_1 
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.a = table_2.a 
GROUP BY a,b,c
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Usually `d` in my scenario is a string, So All I can check is probably `WHERE TABLE_2.d IS NOT NULL`.